# ArcGIS showing error name 'np' is not defined

Tags: python, numpy, arcgis

I have already installed the arcgis library in Python. Used install command:-

```
pip install arcgis
```

However, when I am trying to import the following from arcgis I am facing the following issues:-

```
from arcgis.learn import prepare_data
from arcgis.learn.text import EntityRecognizer
```

Error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-f2fa7a57b88a> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 from arcgis.learn import prepare_data
      3 from arcgis.learn.text import EntityRecognizer

c:\users\*****\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\__init__.py in <module>
     15 
     16 if not _LAMBDA_TEXT_CLASSIFICATION:
---> 17     from .models import (
     18         SingleShotDetector,
     19         UnetClassifier,

c:\users\*****\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\models\__init__.py in <module>
      2 
      3 if not _LAMBDA_TEXT_CLASSIFICATION:
----> 4     from ._ssd import SingleShotDetector
      5     from ._unet import UnetClassifier
      6     from ._retinanet import RetinaNet

c:\users\*****\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\models\_ssd.py in <module>
----> 1 from ._arcgis_model import ArcGISModel, _get_device
      2 from pathlib import Path
      3 import json
      4 from ._codetemplate import code
      5 import warnings

c:\users\******\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\models\_arcgis_model.py in <module>
     33     if not _LAMBDA_TEXT_CLASSIFICATION:
     34         from fastai.vision.learner import model_meta, _default_meta
---> 35         from .._utils.common import get_post_processed_model
     36         from torchvision import models
     37 

c:\users\******\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\_utils\common.py in <module>
    125 
    126 
--> 127 class ArcGISMSImage(Image):
    128     def show(
    129         self, ax=None, rgb_bands=None, show_axis=False, title=None, return_ax=False

c:\users\******\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\arcgis\learn\_utils\common.py in ArcGISMSImage()
    180 
    181     @classmethod
--> 182     def open(cls, path, cast_to=np.float32, div=None, imagery_type=None):
    183         path = str(os.path.abspath(path))
    184         if not os.path.exists:

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

I have uninstalled arcgis and then once again installed it. I have also uninstalled and installed numpy and imported as np once again.

Yet the problem is persisting.

Comment: This doesn't look like a problem with not having *numpy* installed. It looks like a problem with *.../site-packages\arcgis\learn\_utils\common.py* Does this file have `import numpy as np` in it anywhere? The error looks like what you would get if this `import` statement was missing.